# PSExec -c flag does not work with powershell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access, sysinternals, pstools

I'm using PSExec 2.4 to run commands on multiple computers. If I want to run a local batch script on the target computer (named `{machine}` below), this works no problem:

`psexec -i \\{machine} -nobanner -u {user} -p {pw} -c "C:\Users\Joe\Downloads\temp.bat"`

however, as soon as it's a powershell script:

`psexec -i \\{machine} -nobanner -u {user} -p {pw} -c "C:\Users\Joe\Downloads\temp.ps1"`

I get this error:

```
PsExec could not start temp.ps1 on {machine}:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does the ExecutionPolicy allow PowerShell execution on the target machine? Also keep in mind that executing a ps1 file on command-line locally without psexec does not work, so why should it work through psexec? Better try `psexec -s \\{machine} ... Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\Joe\Downloads\temp.ps1`

Comment: In addition to this, if you look at your ***PATHEXT*** variable, you will find that .BAT is on it and .PS1 is not.  PATHEXT tells windows what file extensions it will allow to be run without using the host exe in the command line.  Not sure this is the case here.. but *probably* is.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, adding `.PS1` to the `PATHEXT` variable didn't change anything, unfortunately; I still get the same "cannot find the file specified" error. Same issue if I try other extensions that are on the pathext variable (such as .py for python scripts).

Comment: @Robert, I was only able to get it to work by referencing a powershell script on a shared network drive and specifying the session ID. In other words, it doesn't seem possible to use the `-c` as intended for powershell scripts, since PSExec isn't actually copying the script to the target computer. It only works for `.bat` files.